# C++ Partial Ordering Fails with 2 Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

So given the following template functions with partial specialization

```
template<typename T>
void foo(vector<T> &in) {
    cout << "vector" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T &in) {
    cout << "scalar" << endl;
}

int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<double> a;
    double b;

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem compiling with g++ 3.4.6 and get the expected output:

```
vector
scalar
```

Now, if I add a second template parameter:

```
template<class U, typename T>
void foo2(vector<T> &in) {
    U a;
    cout << "vector" << endl;
}

template<class U, typename T>
void foo2(T &in) {
    U a;
    cout << "scalar" << endl;
}
```

and call it with the following:

```
int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<double> a;
    double b;

    foo2<double>(a);
    foo2<double>(b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it GCC 3.4.6 gives me an ambiguous overload error.

```
error: call of overloaded `foo2(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)' is ambiguous
note: candidates are: void foo2(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_T2> >&) [with U = double, T = double]
note:                 void foo2(T&) [with U = double, T = std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >]
```

I fail to see how the second template parameter now makes the overload ambiguous. As far as I can tell the vector version should still be more specialized. Is this just a bug in 3.4? Is there a workaround?

For the record the code works in gcc 4.1 without issue. Unfortunately some of our tools are still tied to 3.4 so that upgrading isn't the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Does gcc 3.4 work properly when you explicitly give all of the template arguments?

Comment: Also, the title of this is misleading.  Partial ordering has a specific mathematical meaning.  What you're talking about is partial template specification.

Comment: Further, it's not even partial specialization. Only classes can be partially specialized. Template functions are overloaded.

Comment: @andand I tried explicitly giving both template arguments. Strangely it removed the ambiguity error but it always selected the void foo2(T &in) form. i.e foo2<double,vector<double> >() reports scalar. Thanks for the suggestion.

As for calling this partial ordering; this is what all the relevant searches I found called it. Not quite sure what else I would call it. Perhaps template function overload resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to [this defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#214) which is [fixed](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43559) in the latest version of the compiler. Workarounds are to explicitly set all arguments of the template or to use functor instead:

```
template<typename U>
struct foo2 {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()( std::vector<T> &in ) {
        U a;
        cout << "vector" << endl;
    }
    template<typename T>
    void operator()( T& in ) {
        U a;
        cout << "scalar" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<double> a;
    double b;

    foo2<double>()(a);
    foo2<double>()(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that bug report during my searches but it didn't really give me a work around. Using the functor seems to have solved my problem though. Again, thanks.